# What event is raised when a file is added to a project?

Tags: visual-studio, vsx, extensibility

What are the events that are raised when a new or existing file is added/removed to/from a project (.vcproj or .csproj)?

I actually want to handle all possible events that might change the project structure in terms of added or removed project items.

This is in the context of creating add-ins for Visual Studio. Can anybody tell me atleast on event name so that I can look it up?

Comment: you talking about add ins? with version of visual studio?

Comment: yup, exactly. Call it VS Extensibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you will need to listen to  ItemAdded, ItemRemoved, ItemRenamed of ProjectsEvents in Namespace EnvDTE. Here the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectsevents(VS.80).aspx) link.